# Spark only running one executor for big gz files

Tags: apache-spark

I have input source files(compressed .gz) which I need to process using Spark. Each file is 5 GBs (compressed gz) and there are around 11-12 files.
But when I give the source as input, spark just launches one executor. I understand that this may be due to the non-splittable nature of the file but even when I use a high RAM box e.g c3.8xlarge, it still doesnot use more executors. the executor memory being assigned is 45 GB and the executor cores as 31.

Comment: can you give more details about which method you use to read input and submit command ???

Comment: using emr to do the same : 
val sparkStepConf=new HadoopJarStepConfig()
      .withJar("command-runner.jar")
      .withArgs("spark-submit",
                "--executor-memory",executorMemory,
                "--deploy-mode", "cluster",
                "--driver-memory",driverMemory,
                "--executor-cores",executorCores,
                //"--num-executors","12",
                //"--conf","spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true",
                "--class",runClass, jarPathInS3, inputPathsForSpark,outputPathForDataFeed)